# CakePHP - linking models together

Tags: cakephp

I have a few Tables/Models and I want to show the content of the models in one view.

My Schema:

[image]

My Models:

Adress:

```
var $name = "Adress";
public $belongsTo = array("Customer", "Country");

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Contactperson' => array(
        'className' =>  'Contactperson'
    )
);
```

ContactPerson:

```
    var $name = "Contactperson";
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Adress' => array(
                'className' =>  'Adress'
        )
);
```

Country:

```
var $name = "Country";
public $hasMany = "Adress";
```

Customer:

```
    var $name = "Customer";
public $hasMany = array(
        'Adress' => array(
                'className' => 'Adress',
                'order' => array('Adress.mainadress DESC', 'Adress.created DESC')
        )
);
```

My CustomerController:

```
    $customer = $this->Customer->findByid($customerId);
    $this->set('customer', $customer);
```

The return value is the content of the customer and the adress table but I want to get the content of every table.

I want to get a array with the content from customers, addresses, contactpeople and countries.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to establish the correct [recursive level](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive). Try the `find` with different values to understand how it limits your result set.  Ultimately, you will probably want to use the [containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you setup and linking each table correctly (with foreign key and db design), then you can retrieve all the related field easily with CakePHP.

Read up on CakePHP containable.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Recursive will also works, but higher recursive value can hurt your system if its getting too big.